# Inserting date back to database after selecting it and assigning to variable

Tags: mysql, node.js, date, datetime, node-red

have a following problem.
I'm doing a select query from one table and the assign it to variables. It's fine. gives back f.e.:

> "2019-06-14T15:25:15.000Z"

but when I do a 'insert into' query to another table with this variable then in table the entry is showing

> "[BLOB - 39 B]"

(which is downloadable and contains correct date) instead of the date itself. How can I make it to insert the date?

Comment: How do you insert it? Where do you insert it?

Comment: @tadman I edited the question, now it inserts but instead of the date it gives me a blob-39b

Comment: Still zero Node code here, which is a problem. We need to know what you're doing. How you insert this value is especially important. If you're inserting a Date object directly that may not work. Are you using Sequelize?

Comment: [{"id":"d51e5ee8.d0126","type":"function","z":"fcab3f38.7b844","name":"","func":"var myVar=msg.payload[0].date;\nmsg.topic=\"insert into table_2 (date) values ('\"+myVar+\"')\";\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":390,"y":240,"wires":[["af65192b.e59808"]]}]

Comment: @tadman here you go

Comment: It's best to add code as an edit to your question. It's virtually unreadable in comments.

Comment: With something like [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com) you can easily use placeholder values which are the key to proper escaping. Here you're using concatenation which is where *tons* of problems occur.